# Getting Null pointer Exception for extent report

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Getting Null pointer Exception for extent report (Same code working fine in other laptop)

```
public class testreport {

  public static ExtentReports report;
  public static ExtentTest test;
  static WebDriver driver;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    report=new   ExtentReports("D:\\test.htm",true,DisplayOrder.OLDEST_FIRST,NetworkMode.ONLINE);
    test=report.startTest("Testing");

    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(URL);

  } 
}
```

i have been created 20 scripts by same pattern in one laptop and it is working good i haven't get any null pointer exception for extent report.

After i configured everything in second laptop and try to execute the script it is displaying following error...

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.Report.(Report.java:606) at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.(ExtentReports.java:72) at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.(ExtentReports.java:139) at testpage.testreport.main(testreport.java:20)

Comment: have u debug ur code?

Comment: yes i have debug code webdriver getting correct link but when it is reach to Extent report initialization it is throwing Null pointer Exception

Comment: Try creating a sample test.htmlfile and see whether it works fine.

Comment: I got issue why it is happen because i created my own library and supported .jar file i build path in own library once i remove from my library and add separately it worked fine